# React Native - How to fill Image inside TouchableOpacity?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve this look:

[image]

The one I'm getting is this:

[image]

Here's my styling:

```
adsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    top: responsiveWidth(5),
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  playAdButton: {
    width: responsiveWidth(73),
    height: responsiveWidth(15),
    borderRadius: 15,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  playAdImage: {
    width: null,
    height: null,
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 15
  },
```

Here's my component:

```
<View style={styles.adsContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playAdButton}>
              <Image source={require('../../../../assets/images/play-ads.png')} style={styles.playAdImage}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Comment: can you try removing     alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' from  adsContainer

adsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    top: responsiveWidth(5),
  },

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know.

```
playAdImage: {
  width: null,
  height: null,
  flex: 1,
  borderRadius: 15,
  alignSelf: 'center', //add this

},

playAdButton: {
  width: responsiveWidth(73),
  height: responsiveWidth(15),
  borderRadius: 15,
  alignItems: 'center', //add this
  flexDirection: 'row',//add this
},
```

If it doesnt work, we may also know what the function **responsiveWidth** does

Answer (score 0):

try using Stylesheets absoluteFillObject

```
playAdImage: {
width: null,
height: null,
...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
flex: 1,
borderRadius: 15
},
```